# Using Node 12 with webpacker 5 leads to exceptions in my rails application

Tags: node.js, webpacker

I upgraded @rails/webpacker version in package.json from 4.0.2 to 5.4.3, and node version from 10.16.0 to 12.13.1 and got the following error in the browser console of my rails application after doing yarn install:

```
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: dist/index.es.js: unknown Statement of type "ForOfStatement"
    at Emitter.Ep.explodeStatement (:3000/node_modules/regenerator-transform/lib/emit.js:593:13)
    at Object.getConstructor (fromRequireContextWithGlobalFallback.js:15:1)
    at Object.mountComponents (index.js:92:1)
(anonymous) @   fromRequireContextWi…lobalFallback.js:21
mountComponents @   index.js:92
./node_modules/react_ujs/react_ujs/index.js.ReactRailsUJS.handleMount   @   index.js:153
```

Taking hints from the stack trace i have tried upgrading in package.json:

```
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "react_ujs": "^2.4.4",
```

but no luck yet. Has anyone else experienced this before? Any tips to debug this further?
To me, this looks like an incompatibility between Node 12, webpacker 5.4.3 and babel/react_ujs but I'm unable to debug. Looking forward to some help.

Some additional info if it helps:

node --version
v12.13.0

rails -v
Rails 6.0.5.1

Comment: Node 12 is not supported anymore. It was discontinued on May 1st, the current LTS version is v16, with the oldest "technically still supported" version being v14. Any problems with current versions of Node packages not working is caused by using a dead version of Node: upgrade that to the current LTS first. Then resolve any dependency issues (because a bunch of packages from the Node 12 era are now themselves quite dead, having been replaced by newer solutions as well)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for your comment :) I'm trying to upgrade to Node 16 but am doing it in steps: 10->12->14->16 to make the testing easier.

Comment: _First_ update Node, and leave all your dependencies alone. Then only update those versions of packages that no longer work, and _only_ to the minimal version necessary for the new version of Node you're now on. Then repeat that process until you're on Node 16, and you can start setting all dependencies to their latest version.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i tried that and was getting: 

`1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: make failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
gyp ERR! node -v v16.17.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0`

so thought it was too big of a jump. These errors went away when i tried upgrading webpacker but that lead to new incompatibilities and so on.

Comment: Put that information in  your post, and then show the actual full gyp log, because as a comment that's nowhere near enough information to tell you, or us, what's really gone wrong. Familiarity with node-gyp would suggests that's a fully expected error due to not having bumped up webpacker _just enough_ to be a valid Node 12 target. Never bump it up to "the latest version", find the version that was meant for Node 12 and then use that.

Comment: Having said that: https://github.com/wearereasonablepeople/webpacker is clearly no longer supported (and they forgot to issue an `npm deprecate` so you won't see that note anywhere _except_ on github itself), so you might be completely out of luck and need to find a new library because this one's not been updated since November 2020.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans is there an easy way or command to find out the dependancy versions for node 12? For eg. how can i find out the webpacker version meant for node 12?

Comment: Also we are using @rails.webpacker so the repo still seems upto date: https://github.com/rails/webpacker

Comment: Not that I know, but there might be. You'd have to search for one, which might take longer than just doing a parallel "use Node 16 to do a clean install of your dependencies" and then copying your own code over. Also: note that the rails/webpacker repo starts with the text "Webpacker has been retired" in giant font. So it might still be getting the incidental update, but it's clearly also no longer supported.